# Docker Compose Use Domain Instead of Local Host

Tags: php, docker

Sorry I am brand new to docker and web development in general but I made basic docker compose server that hosts my local PHP file and displays some text. It works fine with the local host but I bought some domains and was wondering how I change from connecting to localhost to a domain so anyone can connect to it. My IP is already set up for outside connect and works for my ssh server so I do not need to do that. I just can't seem to find any results when I try to look it up. So I just need to know what to change in my docker compose files or settings to make go a domain instead.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
services:
  product-service:
    build: ./product
    volumes:
      - ./product:/usr/src/app
    ports: 
      - 5001:80

  website:
      image: php:apache
      volumes:
        - ./website:/var/www/html 
      ports:
        - 5000:80
      depends_on:
        - product-service
```

Comment: Are you able to login via SSH using your domain name instead of the IP address?

Comment: @sneep yes SSH works perfectly with my domain name instead of my IP

Comment: Did you already setup the DNS A-Record for your domain to point to your IP?

Comment: Did you touch the indenting at all? It is pretty weird. If it actually starts, this is running on a linux machine right? Because on windows/macos docker runs in a VM and has no access to the public IPs of the machine by default.

Answer (score 1):

Without more knowledge about your code logic, I'm not sure if I can fully make it run just by this answer. But I guess I can give an abstract checklist.

Due to your docker-compose config, the port 5001, 5000 already being opened to localhost. If these ports are already configured to open to the external network, you can already type yourdomain.com:5000 to access it.

If you just want to access by typing `yourdomain.com` (without port). I assume your `website` service will serve it:

- Open port `80` and connect it with port `80` of the `website` service:

```
website:
      image: php:apache
      volumes:
        - ./website:/var/www/html 
      ports:
        - 80:80
      depends_on:
        - product-service
```

- Make sure any AJAX call to `product-service` API will be called to `yourdomain.com:5001`:

From inside the `website` service, it can call to `product-serivce` API by using `localhost:5001`. But from user browser, any AJAX call will be counted as external call, so any AJAX call to this service must be configure as `yourdomain.com:5001`